# Objective-c: How to release memory for AvAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, audio

I have a sound file that I use throughout my program:

```
NSString *soundPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mysound" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundFile1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundPath1];   
soundFilePlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile1 error:nil];
[soundFilePlayer1 prepareToPlay];
```

So soundFilePlayer1 is defined in my .h file because I need it to be global.

Now... do I need to release soundFilePlayer1 and soundFile1? (and soundPath1?)

If so... where do I do this?
I think I need to release soundFilePlayer1 in: (but do I need to stop it first since it may be playing when they exit the program?)

```
- (void)dealloc {
   [soundFilePlayer1 release];
}
```

what about the other files... where do I release those?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember a simple rule of thumb.  Only release if you have called `alloc`, `init`, or `new` on the object.  So, you'll want to release `soundFile1`.  Alternatively, you can use a convenience method and have the sound file added to the autorelease pool automatically:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; //autoreleased
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];

if([player prepareToPlay]){
    [player play];
}
```

And yes, you can release `player` (`soundFilePlayer1`) in `dealloc`, but if you're not looping the audio file there's a better way.  Conform to the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`:

```
@interface YourView : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> { //example
```

Then implement the method here:

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    //your audio file is done, you can release safely
    [player release];
}
```

Comment: but if I release the player, then I'll need to re-allocate it every time I use it no? (I play this file multiple times in the program.. not looping, just playing every time i do something in the program)

Comment: Yes you will need to reallocate it.  However, you don't want to keep the player in memory if you're not using it that often.  Better to keep your memory usage low.